# Do any Geonim or Rishonim adopt/incorporate teachings from Philo?

Tags: commentaries, rishonim, geonim

Do any early commentators from the geonim or rishonim periods cite any teachings from [Philo Judeas](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/12116-philo-judaeus) by name?

Comment: You may want to see Naomi Cohen's article in the Summer 2011 edition of Tradition. http://traditionarchive.org/news/_pdfs/0009-0018.pdf

Comment: Your title and question seem inconsistent.  Are you interested in his ideas being adopted (which implies agreement, using his ideas) or citation by name (which does not necessitate agreement)?

Comment: try http://www.amazon.com/Torah-Alexandria-Biblical-Commentator-Volume/dp/0692291725/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1413285323&sr=8-1&keywords=torah+from+alexandria

Comment: R' Azariah dei Rossi (Min Ha'adumim) discusses Philo's works in his work Meor einayim: part 3, chapter 3-7, he calls him by his Jewish name ידידיהו האלכסנדרי. https://books.google.com/books?id=VwVIAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA95&lpg=PA95&dq=%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95+%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%99&source=bl&ots=FbpRwWHEpI&sig=hmD_xukT5rTcMa1iiKUuVfzDi2U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiq6IS64tvUAhULaz4KHaGTDNsQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%20%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%99&f=false

Comment: @DoubleAA pdf link broken, sounded interesting

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, Philo and his works were studied only by the Church and classicists until Azariah del Rossi. His works weren't translated to Arabic as other philosophical works were, perhaps because they were ironically perceived as Christian... After del Rossi, R. Yehuda Moscato and Yashar of Candia (R. Yosef Shlomo Rofeih Delmedigo) quote and discuss Philo. As far as I know he is not mentioned anywhere in Geonim or Rishonim. It should be noted that similar ideas are found throughout Chazal, RSG, and Rishonic philosophers... He may, though, be referenced as Aleksandri in the commentary to Sefer Yetzirah attributed to Abusahal Dones ibn Tamim though probably originally of R. Yitzchak Yisraeli...